# What is the effect of simple transformations to predictor and/or response variables to the correlation constant (r)?

Tags: regression, correlation, linear-model

Context: A study of living conditions in 55 large U.S. cities found the mean January temperature (degrees Fahrenheit), altitude (feet above sea level), and latitude (degrees north of the equator). Here’s the correlation matrix:

[image: Correlation Matrix]

Question 1. If the temperature were measured in degrees Celsius, what would be the correlation between temperature and latitude?

Question 2: If the temperature were measured in degrees Celsius and the altitude in meters, what would be the correlation? Explain.

So far I've been able to conclude that the correlation would not change from those shown in the correlation matrix shown above. However, I can't seem to devise a sound reason for this.

Can anyone help with this???